# How can I cover this contact owner assignment in test class after lead convert?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, lead-conversion

I have written a trigger helper method that converts to contact and associates the contact with an existing account. The contact owner becomes the owner of the account as shown in this snippet

Now I dont know how to cover this assignment:  `c.OwnerId = c.Account.OwnerId;`

I am getting the error :

> Error occured while converting the Lead to a Contact in convertLeadToContact methodSObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Account

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
// contains the list of created contacts after conversion
contList =  [select Id, OwnerId from Contact where Id IN :cidList]; 
            
//update contact owner with related account owner
if(cidList.size() > 0){
    for(Contact c : contList){
          c.OwnerId = c.Account.OwnerId;
    }
    update contList;
}
```

Comment: Have you read through [this canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/365591/81648) and its linked resources? If so and you still are stuck, please edit your question to add the test code you have so far - including any pertinent test data setup.

Comment: After re-reading, I am unsure what you are asking. Are you asking, as your question title indicates, how to cover that line of code from your test class?  Or are you asking, as the body of your question more indicates, about an error in your original code that makes your trigger not functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To answer the error question...*

This is one of those cases where the error correctly tells you what the issue is.

`...row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Account`

From *Apex Developer Guide > Working with SOQL and SOSL Query Results https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_working_with_results.htm* :

> SOQL and SOSL queries only return data for sObject fields that are selected in the original query. If you try to access a field that was not selected in the SOQL or SOSL query (other than ID), you receive a runtime error, even if the field contains a value in the database.

To rectify:

1. Find where you have SOQL in your code snippet:

   ```
   contList =  [select Id, OwnerId from Contact where Id IN :cidList];
   ```
2. Find everywhere you reference fields using the variable which holds the results returned from your query:

   ```
   c.OwnerId
   c.Account.OwnerId
   ```
3. Compare the items in #2 to what you queried in #1:

   ```
   OwnerId
   ```

   Did I query for OwnerId? **YES**

   ...

   ```
   Account.OwnerId
   ```

   Did I query for Account.OwnerId? **NO**
4. Add `Account.OwnerId` to your query.

Comment: Thanks for that. I managed to update the test based on 3.

Comment: Great! | I was wondering how #3 helped you, when I realized that from the Q/A screen that the last two numbered items both appeared as "3."  But when I am in edit mode for this answer: A) the last numbered item reads as "4." and B) the 2nd item in #3 lines up with the indention of the 1st item. Somehow after re-saving, the last numbered item now appears (for me) correctly as "4."; but I can't get the other items to line up.

Comment: Removed the horizontal line and things line up vertically now. Sorry - that just bothered the heck out of me.